# How to include git revision of image layer in boot output or /etc/issue?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I'm creating a Poky image for an SBC, and I want to have a way for a user to look up the SHA1 ID of the recipe file used to create the image.

Recipe contents are as follows:

```
SUMMARY = "Toradex Embedded Linux Console Sporian Yocto version"
DESCRIPTION = "A Yocto Poky build derived from core-image-minimal"

LICENSE = "MIT"

#start of the resulting deployable tarball name
export IMAGE_BASENAME = "Sporian-Console-Image-Yocto"
IMAGE_NAME_apalis-imx6 = "Apalis-iMX6_${IMAGE_BASENAME}"

require /home/rdepew/workspace/oe-core3/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh \
    sqlite3 \
    avro-c \
"
```

Here's the console output when the SBC boots:

```
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.4.3 apalis-imx6 /dev/ttymxc0

apalis-imx6 login: root
root@apalis-imx6:~# uname -a
Linux apalis-imx6 4.1.44-2.7.4+gb1555bfbf388 #1 SMP Tue Oct 9 17:35:02 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@apalis-imx6:~#
```

Here are the contents of /etc/issue. Note that these are the default contents:

```
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.4.3 \n \l
```

Suppose the SHA1 ID of the repository containing the recipe is ea4c5bb42e7542... . I want to print the SHA1 ID during bootup or in response to a user command (similar to 'uname'). How can I do that?

I thought that ${SRCPV} might be the solution to my problem, but I can't bend it to my will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux and U-Boot git hashes are the ones from the Linux/U-Boot git repository. This is how it is commonly done with OpenEmbedded. There is certainly a way to pass the git hash from OE to the U-Boot/Kernel build system, but I would not recommend doing that since it is not how it is commonly done.

As for the `/etc/issue` file, this typically gets generated in the `meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb` recipe. It should be fairly straight forward to add a bbappend to your layer and extend the task, e.g. something like this:

```
def get_layer_rev(d):
    return bb.process.run('git rev-parse HEAD')

LAYER_REV="${@get_layer_rev(d)}"

do_install_basefilesissue_append() {
    # Overwrite /etc/issue with a custom version of it
    printf "${DISTRO_NAME} " > ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
    printf "${LAYER_REV}" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
}
```

Comment: Note: In newer versions of bitbake replace `do_install_basefilesissue_append()` with `do_install_basefilesissue:append()`

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but I realized that [falstaff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52859985/2235486) actually does not save the git revision
of the layer of the recipe, but instead the git revision of the layer where the build directory is located (or fails if the build directory is not in a git repository).

Hence I ended up using something like this `git-revision-file.bb`:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
SUMMARY = "Place a git revision file in the sysroot"

inherit image-buildinfo

REVISION_INFO_FILE = "build-layers-git-revisions"
S = "${WORKDIR}"


python do_configure() {
    full_path = d.expand("${S}/${REVISION_INFO_FILE}")

    with open(full_path, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(get_layer_revs(d))
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/${REVISION_INFO_FILE} ${D}${sysconfdir}
}

FILES_${PN} = "${sysconfdir}"
```

This saves the git branch and revision of each layer of your build in `/etc/build-layers-git-revisions`.
If you instead want only the git revision of you layer use `base_get_metadata_git_revision(path, d)` of the `metadata_scm.bbclass`. But I think the above provides more complete information for your build.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"` to your configuration. This will create a file `/etc/build` containing something like

```
-----------------------
Build Configuration:  |
-----------------------
DISTRO = poky
DISTRO_VERSION = 4.0.1
-----------------------
Layer Revisions:      |
-----------------------
meta              = HEAD:cb8647c08959abb1d6b7c2b3a34b4b415f66d7ee 
meta-poky         = HEAD:79b0270f55d69ecae8ada6dce492b7c561c56cca 
meta-oe           = HEAD:166ef8dbb14ad98b2094a77fcf352f6c63d5abf2
```